# Regex to find exact word containing ampersand match in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find if "&1" (Exact) exists in a string or not with the help of Regular Expression. But I am not getting the correct result.

```
/\b\&1\b/i.test("Order Date is &1")
```

I am getting false result here. What is wrong?

Comment: `\b` doesn't match between the space and the ampersand.

Comment: @georg I am not good with Regular Expression. Please help with exact Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `&` is not alphanumeric, there is no "break" of an alphanumerical sequence between a space and `&`. So you may need the opposite of `\b`, which is `\B`:

```js
console.log(/\B&1\b/.test("Order Date is &1")); // true
console.log(/\B&1\b/.test("Order Date is&1")); // false
console.log(/\B&1\b/.test("&1 is the Order Date")); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

It is little more simple:

```js
console.log(/(^|\W)&1(\W|$)/.test("Order Date is &1"))
```

Comment: But this is also true for /&1/.test("Order Date is&1"). I don't want that.

Comment: @artista_14 Then you should have said so in your question

Comment: @Sébastien I have written Exact word match